Как передать значение переменной из .bat в программу Golang
У меня есть исполняемые .bat файл:
@SET /A A = 3
10.2.exe %A%
pause

Я создаю билд 10.2.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var A int
    fmt.Scan(&A)
    fmt.Println(A * A)
}

Однако после запуска .bat файла программ не принимает значение A, а создает новое значение внутри программы. Как я могу получить @SET /A A = 3?

Сам же решил:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    arg := os.Args[1:]
    value, _ := strconv.Atoi(arg[0])
    fmt.Print("\nКвадрат числа равен: ")
    fmt.Println(value * value)
}

